# Erlang rebar, kernel options

Tags: unit-testing, erlang, rebar, eunit

I am trying to write simple erlang application, using rebar as eunit test runner. Is there any way to redirect annoying log messages into file, without doing it programmatically? Without rebar I can say `erl -kernel error_logger "{file,\"test.log\"}"` to do this, but how I can do it with rebar?

Generalizinig the question, is there any way to pass some application environment settings using rebar, when running tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to my own question. [As discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307575/passing-runtime-arguments-to-erlang-when-running-rebar-eunit), there is a way to pass erlang flags to rebar using ERL_AFLAGS environment variable. So it's possible to create config file with all necessary environment settings, and say `ERL_AFLAGS="-config /path/to/config" rebar eunit`.

Solution of my problem is:

```
echo '[{kernel, [{error_logger, {file, "test.log"}}]}].' > eunit.config
ERL_AFLAGS="-config eunit" rebar eunit
```

Think it is clumsy approach, but it just works.